# Xcode 4 in my Mac App Store says its installed, but it's not

Tags: xcode, app-store

I can't seem to re download xcode 4 as the mac app store thinks that I already have it. I've had this problem before with another app, but could really do with a solution to this problem now as I need xcode for a new work project.

Any help anyone could offer would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

What you download from the app store is actually the Xcode installer, not Xcode itself. You might have the installer knocking around somewhere even if you've removed Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

Execute the downloaded installer located at

```
/Applications/Install Xcode/Install Xcode.app
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure? See `Macintosh HD/Developer/Applications`

Answer (score -1):

Follow the steps:

1. Open Xcode → About Xcode ( Check the Version)
2. If the  version is not 4.2
3. Search → App Store → Click on "App Store" result → Search Xcode → Click "Update Xcode
4. After update, it will not update Xcode automatically.
5. Search "Applications" → Click "Applications" folder.
6. Sort by "Date modified", Select Name: "Install Xcode" Size:1.81 GB Kind: Application.
7. Click "Install Xcode". (Follow the steps)
8. After Update, check the  Version. It will be 4.2.1

Comment: See [Formatting Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).  You don't need to use HTML formatting on StackOverflow.

Comment: I have 4.1 installed and I want 4.3 At step 3 I search for Xcode, and I see it is installed. There is no "Update xcode" option